# In a migration: how to loop through Models and execute a private method in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I have a Post, to which a migration adds a new attribute and table column `short_url`. This attribute is either provided by the user, or, if left blank, automatically created:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :create_short_url

  private
  def create_short_url
    if short_url.blank? || already_exists?(short_url)
      write_attribute :short_url, random_string(6)
    end
  end
  def random_string(length)
   #innards are irrelevant for this question
  end
end
```

In the migration, I want to run through all posts and have the short_url created and saved.

**problem**: `Post.find(:all).each {|post| post.create_short_url}` in the `self.up` is not possible, due to the private scope of the create_short_url method.

**problem**: Looping through posts and `update!`-ing them does not invoke the `before_create :create_short_url`, because it is not before create. Once migrated, I prefer to not have any `before_update` hooks in place: I don't need to change anything on update.

How would you tackle this? Copy over the `random_string()` and associated methods to the migration? Add specific migration helper methods to the `Post`?

Comment: Why not just keep things simple and remove the private?

Comment: I prefer to keep my interfaces clean. I could comment out the "private" for during the migration (works for me) bu that is not very clean, when working in a team where others, or a deployment system needs to migrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the Object method `send` (it doesn't check protected/private).

```
Post.all.each do |post|
  post.send :create_short_url
  post.save!
end
```

An alternative would be (but that could interfere with other migrations running in the same Ruby-process after that):

```
Post.before_save :create_short_url
Post.all.each(&:save!)
```

**Visibility tip:** Most of the time what you really mean is `protected` (see [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Classes#Private)). I recommend to use `protected` instead of `private` in this case.